# Grails Spring security plugin preauthentication

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am a Grails nooblet and i am trying to get started with the spring security plugin. I have some sample code that i am trying to make work but the problem is that i cant really figure out how to use the authentication and i am stuck at the user/password login. I am attaching the relevant code from the project, please help me with this :P

conf/BootStrap.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter('j2eePreAuthFilter',
                    grails.plugin.springsecurity.SecurityFilterPosition.PRE_AUTH_FILTER.getOrder() - 1)
```

conf/BuildConfig:

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"
```

conf/spring/resources.groovy

```
// BEGING: Spring security

simpleMappableAttributesRetriever(
        org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleMappableAttributesRetriever){
    mappableAttributes=['ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN','ROLE_OPS','ROLE_USER'] as Set
}
userRoles2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper(
        org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper){
    convertAttributeToUpperCase=true
}
authenticationDetailsSource(
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource) {
    mappableRolesRetriever=ref('simpleMappableAttributesRetriever')
    userRoles2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper=ref('userRoles2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper')
}
j2eePreAuthFilter(org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter) {
    authenticationManager=ref('authenticationManager')
    authenticationDetailsSource=ref('authenticationDetailsSource')
}
preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService)
preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider(
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider){
    preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService=ref('preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService')
}
// END: Spring security
```

conf/config.groovy

```
/** Spring security config **/
grails.plugin.springsecurity.roleHierarchy = '''
   ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN > ROLE_OPS
   ROLE_OPS > ROLE_USER
'''

grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = [
        'preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider',
        'anonymousAuthenticationProvider',
        'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider']

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = false
```